# Authentication errors

Tags: python, url, python-2.7, authentication

so I have several versions of code written that are supposed to be able to let me log onto a webpage that requires authentication.
Here is the code:

```
import urllib2
import sys
import re
import base64
from urlparse import urlparse

theurl = 'https://canvas.brown.edu/' #this is the real url
#a protected page - need to write the username and password below

username = 'username' #my username is here
password = 'XXXXXXXXX' #my password is here

print "Code begins"

req = urllib2.Request(theurl)
try:
    handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except IOError, e:
    #here we want to fail
        print "Authentification error found"
        pass

else:
    #if we don't fail then the page isn't protected
    print "This page isn't protected by authentication"
    sys.exit(1)

if not hasattr(e, 'code') or e.code != 401:
    #we got an error but not a 401 (need authentication) error
    print "This page isn't protected by authentication"
    print 'but we failed for another reason'
    sys.exit(1)

authline = e.headers['www-authenticate']
#this gets www-athenticate from the headers
#which has the authentication scheme and realm in it

authobj = re.compile(
        r'''(?:\s*www-authenticate\s*:)?\s*(\w*)\s+realm=['"]([^'"]+)['"]''', re.IGNORECASE)
    #this regular expression is used to extract scheme and realm
matchobj = authobj.match(authline)

if not matchobj:
    #if the authline isn't matched by the regular expression then something is wrong
    print 'The authentication header is badly formed'
    print authline
    sys.exit(1)

scheme = matchobj.group(1)
realm = matchobj.group(2)
#here we've extracted the scheme and the realm from the header
if scheme.lower() != 'basic':
    print 'This example only works with BASIC authentication'
    sys.exit(1)

base64string = base64.encodestring(
    '%s:%s'%(username, password))[:--1]
authheader = "Basic %s" %base64string
req.add_header("Authorization", authheader) 
try:
    handle = urllib2.urlopen(req)
except IOError, e:
    #here we shouldn't fail if the username and password is right
    print "It Looks like the username and password is wrong"
    sys.exit(1)
thepage = handle.read()
print "It worked!"
```

I run it and then I get this error:

```
C:\Python27>python authen_example.py
Code begins
Authentification error found
This page isn't protected by authentication
but we failed for another reason
```

And 1) I know that I need authentication for this page
2) The error used to say that the server timed out
3) if possible I'd also like for my code to prompt me to enter the username and password rather than requiring it directly in the code

Sorry for the code-filled post but this has been bugging me for a good two weeks and I'm still getting nowhere with it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 3) `username = raw_input("Username:")`

Comment: Thanks! It's the little things that get me :)

Answer (score 0):

It hard to put working example without account on this server.

Server can check many elements for security - for example cookies, user-agent, session-id.

I start with code similar to this

```
import requests

#username = 'username'
username = raw_input("Username:")

#password = 'XXXXXXXXX'
username = raw_input("Password:")

start_url = 'https://canvas.brown.edu/' #this is the real url

session = requests.Session()

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0'
}

print "Code begins"

response = session.get(start_url, headers=headers)

print response.status_code
print response.url

print "Login"

payload = {
    'username': username,
    'password': password
}

response = session.post(response.url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print response.status_code
print response.url
```

I use Firebug in Firefox to see how browser is "taking" with server - what elements are send to server during login.

Sometimes I use http://httpbin.org to test what my script is sending.

---

For example your server sends `username` and `password` as `j_username` and `j_password`.
So you need:

```
payload = {
    'j_username': username,
    'j_password': password
}
```

Comment: That helps a lot - thanks! Another question though; I'm using windows, not linux, how does that change the [ headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0'] line?
}